# JUnit: testing speed of calculating

Tags: java, junit, execution-time

For example, I have a method which computes two numbers with some of the following operation "addition, subtraction, multiplication, division" and returns result.

```
public int sum(int a, int b) {
   return a + b;
}
```

Is there a way I can test time of execution of the method, if it didn't take longer than 0.5s to calculate?

Comment: Do you want to measure time of execution of the method or restrict the time of the execution of the method?

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could show me both examples.

Comment: You should specify which one you want to know.

Comment: Time of execution of the method.

Comment: Edit the question accordingly. Note that both of my sentences have *time of execution of the method*...

Comment: I'm sorry... I will change now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@Test(timeout=1000)` to annotate your test method.

> Timeout parameter on @Test Annotation (applies to test method)
>
> You can optionally specify timeout in milliseconds to cause a test
>   method to fail if it takes longer than that number of milliseconds. If
>   the time limit is exceeded, the the failure is triggered by an
>   Exception being thrown:

Have a look over [junit doku](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Timeout-for-tests).

Comment: This is actually what I want as the answer.